# Baffled at trying to set cell.image using UIImage: imageNamed:

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I created a plist that contains an NSDictionary structure. The key is a label (which I use to populate tableview cell.text) and the value is a file name that I want to use to 'dynamically' populate cell.image. The exact png filenames are loaded into the project.

To make things easier (so I thought), I load the plist into an NSDictionary, then pull that apart into two arrays (using allKeys and allValues).

In attempting to set a cell image, I dont understand why this works:

```
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bad.png"];
```

and this does not (in simulator - I get an app crash and barfing in debugger):

```
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[rowImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I can put this next line right before the second piece of code and it works just fine, so it appears that I am getting an NSString from objectAtIndex:

```
NSLog(@"Image name: %@", [rowImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

I have also tried creating a temp NSString and assigning [rowImageList objectAtIndex:] to it, then using that NSString to supply imageNamed:.

Here is some info from debugger:

> -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x262d910
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x262d910'

Let me know if you need more info/code.

Edit: Here's how I populate rowImageList:

```
NSArray *myRowImages = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 
myRowImages = [searchFilterList allValues]; 
self.rowImageList = [myRowImages copy]; 
[myRowImages release]; 
//where searchFilterList is an NSDictionary that I loaded from a plist
```

Here's a screenshot of my plist: 
[IMG][[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/14uwffa.jpg]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlPcb.jpg)
[/IMG]

Edit: revised rowImageList population:

```
 NSMutableArray *myRowImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSEnumerator *enumerator = [searchFilterList objectEnumerator];
 id object;

 while ((object = [enumerator nextObject])) {
     [myRowImages addObject:[object objectAtIndex:0]];
 }
 self.rowImageList = myRowImages; //edit: added self. prefix
 [myRowImages release];
```

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to recheck things. rowImageList IS an array, but I assumed that I was 'pushing' NSStrings onto the array (i.e. an array of NSString objects).

Here's how I populate rowImageList:

  NSArray *myRowImages = [[NSArray alloc] init];
  myRowImages = [searchFilterList allValues];
  self.rowImageList = [myRowImages copy];
  [myRowImages release];
- where searchFilterList is an NSDictionary that I loaded from a plist.

Comment: Good lord, that didnt format very well.

Comment: If you are following along, I eventually changed
"rowImageList = myRowImages;" to
"self.rowImageList = myRowImages;"
Was having weird crap happening with trying to use rowImageList later in code.

Comment: I assume "weird crap" included crashing? Without using the accessor, you were over-releasing the object. The new assignment is correct.

Comment: Yes, I believe I was crashing. The 'weird behavior' was that inside cellForRowAtIndex, the array was 'undefined'. As soon as I added the self. prefix, presto, no longer undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double-check the output from NSLog() and make sure it's not an array that contains an NSString. That's what the error is telling you; you're passing an NSArray where an NSString is expected.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct. I was getting an array back instead of a string. I'll post a new (but perhaps still not quite right) version of the array load.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that [rowImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is returning an array and not a string as expected.

The reason why a value is printed is because to print an array also you need to specify %@ in the NSLog statement.

Try debugging the method and check the class of [rowImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]. It will most probably turn out to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your plist is key/string pairs, and you have not somehow wrapped the names in an array?

Comment: I find myself not sure of anything at this point. The plist structure is Dictionary (root) > Array (child) > String (child of array) with 4 pairs of Array/String. I was attempting to copy another example of a plist. My assumption was that I was creating an NSDictionary structure where Array is the key and String is the value. Not sure how clear that  explanation is.

Comment: You're misunderstanding your plist. The keys in your plist are the strings "All Items", "Good Items", etc. The values are arrays. The Strings belong to the arrays. You should add NSLog(@"%@", searchFilterList) and see if you can understand your data structure. How are you loading this plist?

Comment: From the way your array is structured, you'd want to use:

cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[rowImageList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]];

When you use allValues on the Dictionary, you get back an array, containing four arrays - each one of those arrays holds a string.  The NSlog would have printed the array contents so it would look OK, but your image would be nil.